# Problema con Inner Join, no muestra datos

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```php
$mes = $_POST['mes'];
$ano = $_POST['ano'];
$sql = ' 
SELECT teoricas.idusuarios, students.nombre, students.telefono, teoricas.ttotal, practicas.ptotal FROM students 
        INNER JOIN teoricas ON (teoricas.idusuarios = students.idusuarios)
        INNER JOIN practicas ON (practicas.idusuarios = students.idusuarios)
        WHERE teoricas.ttotal != 3 AND practicas.ptotal != 12 AND mes = :mes AND ano = :ano LIMIT 1';
        $statement = $conexion->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute(array(
            ':mes' => $mes,
            ':ano' => $ano
        ));
        $count = $statement->rowCount();

        if (!$statement){
            die("Error");
        }else{
            // echo $count;
            if ($count === 0) {
                $arreglo['mes'] = $ano.$mes;
                echo json_encode($arreglo);
            }else{
                while ($data = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    $arreglo["data"][] = $data;
                    unset($data);
                }
                echo json_encode($arreglo);
                // var_dump($arreglo);
            }
        }
```

El problema es que no me muestra los datos al cargarlo en `json_encode` y si en var_dump
Al poner la consulta en phpmyadmin funciona bien.
Creo que tiene que ver con algo del `while` pero estoy perdido, ya que la base de datos no es grande y tampoco funciona el `LIMIT 1`

ACTUALIZACIÓN
Si subo mis archivos al server funciona correctamente, sera problema de memoria de mi pc? o excesivo consumo por parte de la consulta?

SOLUCIÓN
Ya encontré el problema. Uno de los registros tenia tilde y hacia que la respuesta colapsara.
Lo que hice fue agregar en la conexión la codificación UTF8 quedando:

```
$conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bd;charset=utf8', 'root','');
```

Era un error muy básico pero que me costo encontrar. Espero que le sirva a alguien

Comment: Como muestras los datos? Es una llamada Ajax?

Comment: @alanfcm si, hago un `console.log()` para ver que error tira, y sale la pagina en blanco. 
Lo mismo sucede si lo hago de la pagina en si poniendo las variables a mano